# python code only works if whatever I type in is in between quotation marks

Tags: python, absolute

I was trying to follow an exercise by the book "Python for the absolute beginner" and I kept getting an infinite loop no matter what I did. I googled the answer to see if someone got it and I tried this code: http://pastebin.com/snnuvBLf only to find out that it wasn't working either.

After a while of trying I decided to enter the numbers the program requested in between quotation marks, and it did work. Any reason why this is happening? Is the code, or that I am doing something wrong. or the compiler itself? I am so confused.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to make the most of this fantastic resource, please take a moment to review [help] and in particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Right now your question is attracting close votes instead of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason adding the quotation marks ("") around all your numbers works is because choice is being evaluated as a string rather than an int.

so when you use

```
choice = input("Choose option.")
```

Python 3 [evaluates this as a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (and adding the quotes allows all your if statements and while statements to also evaluate as strings). Instead of having to evaluate everything as a string you can just cast the input to int when its entered with:

```
choice = int(input("Choose option."))
```

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that Python 3 assumed all inputs were strings. I am using Python 2.7. What I did is that I changed all the input sintax to raw_input and it worked. Thanks for your help.